# Compose lazycolumn scrolling below top bar

Tags: kotlin, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, android-actionbar, lazycolumn

I'm struggling with making the lazy column scroll into the top bar. In the lazy column, I have two items: an image and a list of cards with some information. I need the list of cards to be hidden in the top bar when I scroll the lazy column.

**Current result** [image: current scrolling result]

**Expected result** [image: expected scrolling result]

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Transparent),
            title = {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_logo),
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(Screen.Account.route)
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_settings),
                            "backIcon",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }

                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(Screen.Staking.route)
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_staking),
                            "",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                }
            },
            actions = {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.Swap.route)
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_swap),
                        "",
                        tint = Color.White
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.Assets.route)
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_asserts),
                        "",
                        tint = Color.White
                    )
                }
            },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = Color.Transparent
            )
        )
    },
    containerColor = Color(0xFF18192F),
    modifier = Modifier
) { innerPadding ->
    innerPadding
    SwipeRefresh(
        modifier = Modifier,
        state = swipeRefreshState,
        onRefresh = {
            viewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.Refresh)
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            // .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 16.dp)
        ) {

            item(key = "header: 1") {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    GifImage(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(350.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                        image = R.drawable.gif_home_edited,
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )


                    Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)) {
                        var totalAmountUsd = remember {
                            0.0
                        }
                        if (state.error == null && !state.coin.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                            totalAmountUsd =
                                state.coin.sumOf { balance -> balance.balanceUsd ?: 0.0 }
                        }

                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            text = "$${"%.3f".format(totalAmountUsd, Locale.US)}",
                            color = Color.White,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            fontSize = 40.sp,
                            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.circularstdbold)),
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            text = "TOTAL BALANCE",
                            color = Color(0xFFDFE1F6),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall
                        )
                    }

                    Spacer(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(32.dp)
                            .background(
                                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                                    colors = listOf(
                                        Color.Transparent,
                                        Color(0xFF18192E)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    )
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = 12.dp, horizontal = 20.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                        text = "WALLET",
                        color = Color(0xFFA9ADD9),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium
                    )
                }
            }

            if (state.error == null) {
                itemsIndexed(
                    items = state.coin,
                    key = { index, item -> if (index == 0) index else item.id }
                ) { index, item ->
                    CryptoCard(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                        cryptoCardData = item,
                        navController = navController,
                        coinInfo = state.coinInfo,
                        isExpanded = index == expandedCardIndex
                    ) {
                        expandedCardIndex = if (expandedCardIndex == index) {
                            -1
                        } else {
                            index
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            item {
                AssetsExplorer(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, this is how the entire screen looks like:
[image: full screen image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to move the background image out of the `LazyColumn` and apply `innerPadding` to the `LazyColumn`. Then you can scroll the image together with the `LazyColumn` by participating in nested scrolling hierarchy. Read about nested scrolling [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/scroll#nested-scrolling) and `nestedScroll` modifier [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)).

[image]

```
Scaffold(
// ---
) { innerPadding ->
    val imageHeight = 350.dp
    val imageHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { imageHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
    var totalOffsetPx by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    var imageOffsetPx by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                totalOffsetPx = (totalOffsetPx + available.y).coerceAtMost(0f)
                imageOffsetPx = totalOffsetPx.coerceIn(-imageHeightPx, 0f)
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
    val headerHeight = remember { imageHeight - innerPadding.calculateTopPadding() }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)    // Participate in nested scroll
    ) {
        GifImage(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(imageHeight)
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                .offset { IntOffset(0, y = imageOffsetPx.roundToInt()) },
            image = R.drawable.gif_home_edited,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )

        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(innerPadding)                              // Apply padding
                .consumeWindowInsets(innerPadding),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 16.dp)
        ) {

            item(key = "header: 1") {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(headerHeight),                      // Set the header height
// ------------
}
```